# Does matplotlib change np.int to float automatically in x-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wonder why matplotlib changes the np.int to float in drawing especially in x-axis. Is that normal behavior of matplotlib or there might be something wrong in my jupyter status?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ys = np.arange(4)
print(ys)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(16,5))
xs = np.arange(1,5,dtype=np.int)
print(xs)
ax.plot(xs, ys, marker='o')
ax.set_xlabel("dtype = int", fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel("y-values", fontsize=15)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the tick locator, you can set it to integers only. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/ticker_api.html#tick-locating) for details:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.MaxNLocator(integer=True))
```

[image]

Comment: You mean it is not x-values but it is "tick locator". That's very clear.